# Как получить картинку как массив из gstreamer

Tags: python, python-3.x, gstreamer

Я работаю с deepstream.
Пайплайн следующий я дедектирую объект в nvinfer(**yolov5**) и вырезаю только его чтобы передать в nvinfer, но с **unet** (нужно считать количество маленьких объектов).
Как я могу получить конкретный кадр, преобразовать как мне нужно и передать его дальше по пайплайну?

Прошу не судить строго, я только осваиваю gstreamer и не совсем понимаю сейчас все его аспекты

Comment: Я несколько продвинулся. В deepstream_python_apps оказался пример, где можно получить как раз таки numpy массив в RGBA:
` n_frame = pyds.get_nvds_buf_surface(hash(gst_buffer), frame_meta.batch_id)`
Сейчас проблема изменилась. Как можно заменить buf_surface?